# RParsingError: error when running quantmod library in ipynb notebook

Tags: r, ipython, google-colaboratory, quantmod, parsing-error

I am running R code in ipynb of the Google Colab notebook. However, there is `RParsingError` for the code. But, if I replace `0200.KL` with `AAPL`, it works well.

```
%load_ext rpy2.ipython

%%R
library(quantmod)
library(xts)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(rugarch)

getSymbols(Symbols="0200.KL",src="yahoo",from="2020-1-1",to="2021-1-1")
0200.KL
```

However, the error shows as below:

> RParsingError: Parsing status not OK - PARSING_STATUS.PARSE_ERROR

Any ways to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED, below is the code.

```
%%R
library(quantmod)
library(xts)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(rugarch)

getSymbols(Symbols="0200.KL",src="yahoo",from="2016-1-1",to="2021-1-1") # function under quantmod library

REV = `0200.KL`
# remove the original dataframe from your workspace
rm(`0200.KL`)

#change column names
colnames(REV) = c("Open","High","Low","Close","Volume","Adjusted Close")

chartSeries(REV["2020-12"]) # under quantmod, plot dec 2020 ohlc data
chartSeries(REV$Close, theme="white")
```